# Matlab : Sorting rows in decending order

Tags: matlab

I have an array A, I want to arrange each row in descending order to get a new array B. How could I do this ?

E.g.

Array A (original array):

```
11   9   13   10
12   4   1    6  
13   5   12   11
```

Array B (rearranged array):

```
13   11   10   9
12   6    4    1
13   12   11   5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>> A=[11 9 13 10;12 4 1 6;13 5 12 11]

A =

    11     9    13    10
    12     4     1     6
    13     5    12    11

>> sort(A,2,'descend')

ans =

    13    11    10     9
    12     6     4     1
    13    12    11     5
```

For details type: ***`help sort`*** at Matlab command window

Comment: I have deleted my answer. Just noticed same with yours. +1